# What is the maximum number of tables can be created in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a doubt that how many tables can be created in a single database 100 or 200 or 1000...

> What may be the max number of tables that can be created in a single database?

Also, I need to know to say if I create table of some 800 tables in a single database, does it affects the performance while querying?

> Splitting some hundred tables into multiple databases is a good choice? if so why?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum database size can be approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 140,000 gigabytes).

Reference: [The Official SQLite Documentation and limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

> 14. Maximum Database Size
>
> Every database consists of one or more "pages". Within a single
>   database, every page is the same size, but different database can have
>   page sizes that are powers of two between 512 and 65536, inclusive.
>   The maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages. At the
>   maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum
>   database size of approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 128
>   tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes).